# How to get Npgsql working with EF4?

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-4, frameworks, entity, npgsql

hey I know it's an old question but I'm a little stuck trying to even get Npgsql to work with EF4 at all! I can't seem to register the provider wherever it needs to go in order for it to show up in the the Entity Data Model Wizard.

When trying to create a new model, I try and create the connection to the Postgres database in the "Change Data Source" dialog. But the only providers in here are differing flavours of MSSQL and "". The data provider combo on this form doesn't show Npgsql or anything postgres related.

I have already done the usual of registering npgsql and the mono security assemblies in the GAC. I've modified machine.config (32 and 64bit) to have the provider factory entry required.

I'm using VS2010 SP1 on Windows 7 64bit & Npgsql 2.0.11.92. I'm developing for .NET4.

Any ideas of how to get this working would be much appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately Npgsql doesn't have support for VS Wizards. We have a very early work in progress which you can give a try. Checkout our downloads.npgsql.org page and look for the Npgsql.Provider.zip file. Follow the instructions there and let me know if it works ok for you. Again, sorry for the lack of support. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Npgsql doesn't have support for VS Wizards. 
We have a very early work in progress which you can give a try.

Checkout our [downloads page](http://downloads.npgsql.org) and look for the Npgsql.Provider.zip file. 
Follow the install instructions there and let me know if it works ok for you.

Again, sorry for the lack of support.

I hope it helps.